# Run time error on Xamarin.Forms app after deploying to device with android version 2.3

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I debug Xamarin.Forms hybrid app (saving some text box values into table ) on my Galaxy Y ( version 2.3) I get the following error after displaying the message "Deployment completed"

> A java.Lang.RuntimeException was thrown
>
> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.companyname.layoutapp/md5853a211922710cf8711c18a8ac78bfaa.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.animation.ValueAnimator in
>   loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.companyname.layoutapp-2.apk]

Where should I change the configuration settings to avoid this error ?( By the way my device memory is only 190 MB).I am new to app development domain.

Comment: What is the minimum android version you are targeting? Are you able to get it working on an Emulator running 2.3?

Comment: i am targeting minimum version Android 2.3

Comment: Minimum API version is 14 for forms: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17213/minimum-android-version-4-0

Comment: The app is deployed and correctly working on jellybean device.. It was indeed API issue